# Need help creating and plotting a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

This is a meaty question, but it could be useful to other people working with list and tuples.  I need to take the list `CALC_RECORD` and just pull the third element from the list.  The output currently looks something like this: `[('calculation', 1467938304.345363, 1.2636651992797852)]`.  The third element in the tuple is the time it took the player to answer a question.  Each time a question is answered, a new tuple is created in the list.  So it then looks something like this: `[('calculation', 1467938302.2010334, None), ('calculation', 1467938302.8568625, None), ('calculation', 1467938304.345363, 1.2636651992797852)]`.  I need to pull out the third element from each tuple, and create a list using those elements.  That list will then be used as the y-axis in a graph (the x-axis being the total times the game was played.  I tried using lambda with a filter function, but I got nowhere with that.  Any ideas?

NOTE:

There are more games/function in the full version of the program below, but they have been removed to save space since if the question can be answered, the same answer can be used on them.  Thus having them here would be redundant.

EDIT:
I tried to do it like this.

```
#EDIT: filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] =='calculation' and x[2] != None, CALC_RECORD))

import random
from random import randint
import time
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Number of problems for each practice/real round
practice_round = 0
real_round = 3

main_record = []
CALC_RECORD = []

# (1) Calculation Game ---------------------------------------------------------

def calculation():
    response_time = None
    # Determine the min and max calculation values
    min_calculation_value = 1
    max_calculation_value = 10
    # Generate the problems
    print('\nSolve the following problem:')
    a = random.randint(min_calculation_value, max_calculation_value)
    b = random.randint(min_calculation_value, max_calculation_value)
    problem_type = random.randint(1,2)
    if problem_type == 1:
        answer = a * b
        print(a, '*', b)
    elif problem_type == 2:
        answer = a % b
        print(a, '%', b)
    # Get the user's answer determine what to do if correct
    start_time = time.time()
    user_answer = input('\nEnter your answer: ')
    end_time = time.time()
    if user_answer == str(answer):
        response_time = end_time - start_time
        print('You are correct!')
    elif user_answer != str(answer):
        print('You are incorrect.')
    # Return game id, start time, and response time
    return("calculation", start_time, response_time)

def calculation_game():
    record = []
    # Generate two problems for a practice round
    print("\nLet's begin with 2 practice problems.")
    for i in range (practice_round):
        print('\nPractice Problem', i + 1, 'of', practice_round)
        calculation()
    # Generate 10 problems for a real, recorded round
    print("\nNow let's try it for real this time.")
    for i in range (real_round):
        print('\nProblem', i + 1, 'of', real_round)
        # Append records for each iteration
        record.append(calculation())
    main_record.extend(record)
    CALC_RECORD.extend(record)
    return record

# (5) Display Data -------------------------------------------------------------
def display_data():
    print (CALC_RECORD)
#This function is currently just being used to view the output of calc record

----------------------------------------------------------------

def quit_game():
    print('\nThank you for playing!')

# Main Menu --------------------------------------------------------------------

def menu():
    print("\nEnter 1 to play 'Calculation'")
    print("Enter 2 to play 'Binary Reader'")
    print("Enter 3 to play 'Trifacto'")
    print("Enter 4 to view your statistics")
    print("Enter 5 to display data")
    print("Enter 6 to save your progress")
    print("Enter 7 to load data")
    print("Enter 8 to quit the game")

def main_menu():

    print('Welcome--Let's Play!')
    main_record = []
    user_input = ''
    while user_input != '8':
        menu()
        user_input = input('\nWhat would you like to do? ')
        if user_input == '1':
            calculation_game()
        if user_input == '2':
            binary_reader_game()
        if user_input == '3':
            trifacto_game()
        if user_input == '4':
            display_statistics()
        if user_input == '5':
            display_data()
        if user_input == '8':
            quit_game()

main_menu()
```

Comment: What did you try to use? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Right, I meant to post what I tried.  It'll be up in just a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of tuples, and you want to pull out the third element of each tuple into a new list, then the following should work:

```
new_list = [t[2] for t in old_list]
```

Or you can use `map` and `lambda` :

```
new_list = list(map(lambda t: t[2], old_list))

In [11]: old_list = [('calculation', 1467938302.2010334, None), ('calculation', 1467938302.8568625, None), ('calculation', 1467938304.345363, 1.2636651992797852)]

In [12]: old_list
Out[12]: 
[('calculation', 1467938302.2010334, None),
 ('calculation', 1467938302.8568625, None),
 ('calculation', 1467938304.345363, 1.2636651992797852)]

In [13]: [t[2] for t in old_list]
Out[13]: [None, None, 1.2636651992797852]

In [14]: list(map(lambda t:t[2], old_list))
Out[14]: [None, None, 1.2636651992797852]
```

EDIT: Based on the code you added of your initial attempt, you can easily map and filter values with a list comprehension like so:

```
In [15]: [t[2] for t in old_list if t[0] =='calculation' and t[2] != None]
Out[15]: [1.2636651992797852]
```

Comment: Do you a way that I could keep track of the number of times a game was played in a list?  I'm a brand new programmer so to say the least, I'm stuck.

Comment: @kjf545 if you found this answer useful, you can "accept" it by clicking on the checkmark underneath the up-vote,down-vote totals

Comment: Sure thing, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @kjf545 just use a variable as a counter, initialzed outside the while-loop to zero `counter = 0`. You can increment the counter simply by using `counter += 1` inside the while-loop, taking care your logic doesn't over-count or under-count.